# Exclude custom tags from the_tags

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, hide

I use [the_tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags) to display my post tags for my Wordpress site, I use this code:

```
<?php the_tags('',' • ',''); ?>
```

I need to exclude/hide two tags named `featured` and `billed` from the printed list. **What is the most efficient way of doing this?** Please only suggest light solutions, no mental queries that will slow my site which contains thousands of tags and hourly page views.

Comment: Doesn't `the_tags` print out the list, rather than returning it?

Comment: Yes I believe it does, I changed my question accordingly, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only way that is simpler and doesn't load the page I'm thinking of:

```
<?php
    $links = array();
    foreach(get_the_tags() as $this_tag) {
        if ($this_tag->name != "featured" && $this_tag->name != "billed"){
           $links[] = '<a href="'.get_tag_link($this_tag->term_id).'">'.$this_tag->name.'</a>';
        }
    }
    echo implode(' • ', $links);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please elaborate on your answer, is this much heavier than the query that I use?

Comment: what query? `the_tags('',' • ','')`?, no, it's the same thing.

Comment: Update: I just tested your code but it did not work. Nothing appeared on my post. Is there a typo in your code or something missing? No errors were returned either... EDIT: Okay let me try the new version

Comment: +1, except for separator, you could build an array of links and join them

Comment: @soju can you kindly demonstrate how?

Comment: @GaryWoods I just tested the code and works perfect, did you see my update in code?

Comment: @Mihai Yes it works perfectly! Thank you very much for this solution. I do still have a question, do you understand soju's improvement suggestion?

Comment: Updated my answer .. for that approach

Comment: And another way of doing this is to add a filter on `get_the_tags`, or `the_tags`...etc

Comment: Thats the one brother, thank you very much for the answer, I have accepted it.

Comment: @soju what would be the difference in that approach in terms of which that is lighter?